# Why does an in-place member initialization use a copy constructor in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, atomic, copy-constructor

I'm a little bit confused about the following code:

```
struct A {
  std::atomic<int> a = 0;
};
```

Which gives an error:

> copying member subobject of type 'std::atomic' invokes deleted constructor

But almost the same code does work:

```
struct A {
  std::atomic<int> a = {0};
};
```

Okey, if the first variant requires the copy constructor, then it have to use `operator=()`. But wait! This operator perfectly works without the copy constructor:

```
A a;
a.a = 1;
```

Can anyone explain how both of the in-place initializations are expanded in terms of simple operations? Why the first one requires copy constructor?

Comment: Keep in mind, copy assignment does not use the copy constructor.  `std::atomic<int> a = 0` involves the copy constructor. `a.a = 1` is merely assignment, it's not even copy assignment.  I can't answer though, because I don't know why `std::atomic<int> a = {0}` succeeds, I would have expected that to fail.

Comment: @MooingDuck I always thought, that `std::atomic<int> a = 0`, should be equal to `std::atomic<int> a(0)` - without copy constructor, but looks like it's not.

Comment: `std::atomic<int> a = 0` would require a copy constructor _syntactically_, and so the C++ spec says this syntax requires the copy constructor _to be available_.  However, using the copy constructor would be unnecessary overhead, so the C++ spec also says that the copy constructor may be elided, which makes it _behave_ identically to `std::atomic<int> a(0);`.  Note that this behavior still requires the copy constructor _to be theoretically usable_.

Comment: @MooingDuck thanks for explanation, I didn't know that. Your comment contains a half of an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'd started as an answer, but then moved it to the comments because I only knew half :/

Comment: @MooingDuck It doesn't strictly require a copy constructor, a move constructor suffices for copy-initialization.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All references are to N3797, the C++1y current working draft. §8.5 Initializers [dcl.init]/15 states:

> The initialization that occurs in the form
>
> ```
> T x = a;
> ```
>
> as well as in argument passing, function return, throwing an exception (15.1), handling an exception
>   (15.3), and aggregate member initialization (8.5.1) is called *copy-initialization*. [ Note: Copy-initialization may invoke a move (12.8). —end note ]

So the declaration:

```
std::atomic<int> a = 0;
```

is performing copy-initialization. According to 8.5/17:

> The semantics of initializers are as follows. The *destination type* is the type of the object or reference being initialized and the *source type* is the type of the initializer expression. If the initializer is not a single (possibly parenthesized) expression, the source type is not defined.

The *destination type* here is `std::atomic<int>` and the *source type* is `int` (i.e., `decltype(0)`). To determine the semantics of the initialization, we have to determine which of paragraph 17's bullets applies:

> - If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) *braced-init-list*, the object or reference is list-initialized (8.5.4).
> - If the destination type is a reference type, see 8.5.3.
> - If the destination type is an array of characters, an array of `char16_t`, an array of `char32_t`, or an array of `wchar_t`, and the initializer is a string literal, see 8.5.2.
> - If the initializer is `()`, the object is value-initialized.
> - Otherwise, if the destination type is an array, the program is ill-formed.
> - If the destination type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type:
>
>   - If the initialization is direct-initialization, or if it is copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the destination, ... [does not apply, source type is `int`]
>   - Otherwise (i.e., for the remaining copy-initialization cases), user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the source type to the destination type or (when a conversion function
>       is used) to a derived class thereof are enumerated as described in 13.3.1.4, and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3). If the conversion cannot be done or is ambiguous, the
>       initialization is ill-formed. The function selected is called with the initializer expression as its argument; if the function is a constructor, the call initializes a temporary of the cv-unqualified
>       version of the destination type. The temporary is a prvalue. The result of the call (which is the
>       temporary for the constructor case) is then used to direct-initialize, according to the rules above,
>       the object that is the destination of the copy-initialization. In certain cases, an implementation
>       is permitted to eliminate the copying inherent in this direct-initialization by constructing the
>       intermediate result directly into the object being initialized; see 12.2, 12.8.
> - ...

There we are. The initializer expression - `0` - is converted into a `std::atomic<int>` via the creation of a temporary object initialized with the `std::atomic<int>(int)` constructor. That temporary object is used to direct-initialize the original `std::atomic<int>` object. The other of the "(possibly cv-qualified) class type" bullets that we ignored before now applies:

- If the initialization is direct-initialization, or if it is copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the destination, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated (13.3.1.3), and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3). The constructor so selected is called to initialize the object, with the initializer expression or *expression-list* as its argument(s). If no constructor applies, or the overload resolution is ambiguous, the initialization is ill-formed.

Recall that the new initializer is a prvalue `std::atomic<int>`. Overload resolution determines that there is no appropriate `std::atomic<int>` constructor that accepts a single argument `std::atomic<int>&&` (`std::atomic<int>` is not movable or copyable) and diagnoses the program as ill-formed.

For the second part of the question,

```
std::atomic<int> a = {0};
```

is again copy initialization per 8.5/15. This time, however, the very first bullet of 8.5/17 applies:

> - If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) *braced-init-list*, the object or reference is list-initialized (8.5.4).

For *list-initialization*, we must look to 8.5.4/3:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows:
>
> - If `T` is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.1).
> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements and `T` is a class type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized.
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a specialization of `std::initializer_list<E>`, a prvalue `initializer_list` object is constructed as described below and used to initialize the object according to the rules for initialization of an object from a class of the same type (8.5).
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7). If a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed.
> - ...

`std::atomic<int>` is a class type, not an aggregate or `initializer_list` specialization, so constructors are considered. The `std::atomic<int>::atomic(int)` constructor will be selected as a perfect match and is used to initialize the object.

Comment: You want standard references? There's a language-lawyer answer.

Comment: Sadly, the relevant references appear to be missing? §9.2 ad 4 "A brace-or-equal-initializer shall appear only in the declaration of a data member. (For static data members, see 9.4.2; for non-static data members, see 12.6.2)."?

Comment: @sehe The difference in the behavior of the two non-static data member initializers has nothing to do with the fact that they are non-static data member initializers.

Comment: After having read all that, I concur. However, it **is** relevant context, and the fact the semantics are the same is only specified in §12.6.x (about 3 locations). It's nice to explicitely mention that. (You already had my +1)

Comment: What about the form `std::atomic<int> a {0}`, without the equals sign? My reading of `[dcl.init]` is that this is _list-initialization_, equivalent to `= {0}`. But GCC appears to distinguish the two, giving a compilation error for the one without the equals sign due to a deleted copy constructor, whereas Clang does not.

Comment: Can anyone answer @jacobsa ? I'm interested as well (even if GCC 5.4.0 now seems to accept both.

Answer (score 7):

Let consider the first case

```
struct A {
  std::atomic<int> a = 0;
};
```

For this initialization to be successful, there needs to be an accessible copy constructor. But the copy constructor is defined as deleted.

```
atomic(const atomic&) = delete;
```

So the compiler issues an error.

In the second case

```
struct A {
  std::atomic<int> a = {0};
};
```

where an initializer list is used the copy constructor is not required. The compiler searches for a constructor that accepts one `int` argument and such constructor indeed exists, so it is called.

```
constexpr atomic(T) noexcept;
```

or if to substitute template parameter for type int

```
constexpr atomic(int) noexcept;
```

According to the C++ Standard if a class has no constructor with the first parameter of type std::initializer_list (when an initializer list is specified) then

> 3 List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined
>   as follows: ...
>
> Otherwise, if T is a class type, constructors are considered. The
>   applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen
>   through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7). If a narrowing
>   conversion (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments,
>   the program is ill-formed.

In the last case

```
A a;
a.a = 1;
```

this uses an assignment operator

```
T operator=(T) noexcept;
```

or if to substitute template parameter for type int

```
int operator=(int) noexcept;
```

So there is no problem.

Comment: I think that assignment operator at the bottom is slightly ambiguous, I personally would be happier if it were changed to `int operator=(int) noexcept`, which clarifies that it's not a copy-constructor.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Mooing Duck Do you mean that instead of template parameter I should use argument int?

Comment: Sorry, but it seems to me, that you just expressed in english the compiler's actions :) You don't explain, why the compiler behaves this way and not another one. Actually, why the copy constructor is not required in the second case?

Comment: @abyss.7 In the second case copy constructor is not used due to the rules how initializer lists are processed by constructors. I will update my post.

Comment: @abyss.7: These are the rules from the C++ spec, were you desiring quotes?  We can do that if that's what you were expecting.

Comment: @MooingDuck I was really expecting the expanding of initializations, but in the first case there is no expanding - just some C++ spec rules about accessibility of copy constructor. So, now I'm less confused. If the second case can be explained in the terms of spec rules, then let it be so. It's hard to expect some specific explanation, if you don't know how it works.