# Calling std::atomic_fetch_add, getting ''No matching function for call to 'atomic_fetch_add' error

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, deprecation-warning

My background is in Swift and Objective-C, so I'm getting confused by this behaviour in a C++ file I'm working on.

First of all, this line:

```
OSAtomicIncrement32Barrier(&changeCounter);
```

In Xcode it shows the warning:

> 'OSAtomicIncrement32Barrier' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use std::atomic_fetch_add() from <atomic> instead

No sweat. I import `<atomic>` and replace the line with:

```
std::atomic_fetch_add(&changeCounter, 1);
```

But now I get a full-blown error:

> No matching function for call to 'atomic_fetch_add'

`changeCounter` is defined thus:

```
volatile int32_t changeCounter = 0;
```

I've also tried it as a `volatile int`. But no change.

I used code completion to get that function, and as far as I can tell I'm putting the correct arguments in. Documentation I can find (for example, [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_fetch_add)) shows `atomic_fetch_add` in use and I appear to be doing it the same way.

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Note that `changeCounter` needs to be `std::atomic<int32_t >`  See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_fetch_add  Also in current c++ `volatile` has nothing to do with multi-threading.

Comment: @RichardCritten I'll check out the `atomic<int32_t>` type, cheers. This file was originally written by Apple, `volatile` was there to start with.

Comment: @RichardCritten I've changed `changeCounter` to `std::atomic<int32_t>`, but now I'm getting this error: "Copying member subobject of type 'std::atomic<int32_t>' (aka 'atomic<int>') invokes deleted constructor"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RichardCritten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3370124/richard-critten) put me on the right track, but it required a little more fettling beyond that. The main solution is that I changed the definition of `changeCounter` from

```
volatile int32_t changeCounter = 0;
```

to

```
std::atomic<int32_t> changeCounter = {0};
```

Note the curly brackets around `0`: this is because there is no copy constructor for `std::atomic<int32_t>`, so using just `0` gives the error

> Copying member subobject of type 'std::atomic' (aka 'atomic') invokes deleted constructor

According to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21708950/8653957), placing the value to assign in curly braces avoids the use of a copy constructor, thus fixing that issue.